# Zend_Auth checking if user is logged in

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-auth

I tried using:

```
// do login if request is posted
if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
    // do authencation
    ...
} else {
    // request not posted
    // see if already logged in
    if (Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity()) {
        echo "already logged in as: " . Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity();
    }
}
```

`Zend_Auth::getInstance()->hasIdentity()` seem to be always false ... even after a login

Comment: how do you do your authentication? how do you make sure it is persisted? if you have done authentication right, hasIdentity will return true!

Comment: i used Zend_Auth for authentication, http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.auth.html#zend.auth.introduction.persistence.default, according to that $result->getIdentity() === $auth->getIdentity()

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you ever calling `Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getStorage()->write($identity)`?

If you are authenticating through `Zend_Auth::getInstance()->authenticate($adapter)` it will write to storage for you, but if you are calling authenticate directly on the adapter, you are responsible for writing the identity to the storage.

Answer (score 1):

are you sure your identity is persisted? (ie. stored in the session or somthing similar)
if not you will have to re-authenticate on each request

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem, 
in my case the value of `session.save_path` on was not set on my server (`phpinfo()`)
so i added in `configs/application.ini` this value:

```
resources.session.save_path = APPLICATION_PATH "/../data/sessions"
```

and on my server i create the dir `/data/sessions` where `sessions` has 777 permissions